# ./configure error installing PHP with Kerberos support on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, php, kerberos

I am trying to install PHP on Ubuntu 11.04. I am compiling from source.

Here are my installation dependencies:

```
apt-get -y install php5-dev php-pear

apt-get -y install libxml2-dev libevent-dev zlib1g-dev libbz2-dev libgmp3-dev
libssl-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev libjpeg-dev libpng-dev libgd2-xpm-dev
libmcrypt-dev memcached libmemcached-dev libc-client-dev libkrb5-dev
```

And here is my configure script:

```
./configure --enable-fpm --enable-cli --with-fpm-user=php-fpm
--with-fpm-group=php-fpm --prefix=/usr/local/php --exec-prefix=/usr/local/php
--with-config-file-path=/usr/local/php/etc
--with-config-file-scan-dir=/usr/local/php/etc
--enable-bcmath --enable-ctype --with-curl --with-curlwrappers --enable-dba
--with-cdb --with-flatfile --with-inifile --enable-exif --enable-ftp
--disable-fileinfo --with-gd --with-jpeg-dir --with-png-dir --with-zlib-dir
--with-xpm-dir --with-ttf --with-freetype-dir --enable-gd-native-ttf
--with-gettext --with-gmp --with-imap --with-imap-ssl --with-ldap
--with-ldap-sasl --enable-mbstring=all --with-mcrypt --with-mhash --with-mysql
--with-mysqli --with-pdo-mysql --with-openssl --with-kerberos --with-pspell
--enable-shmop --enable-simplexml --with-snmp --enable-soap --enable-sockets
--with-tidy --enable-wddx --enable-xmlreader --with-xmlrpc --with-xsl
--with-zip --with-zlib --enable-sysvsem --enable-sysvshm
```

However, I get the following error:

```
configure: error: Kerberos libraries not found.

Check the path given to --with-kerberos (if no path is given, searches in
/usr/kerberos, /usr/local and /usr )
```

I did not provide a path, but there is no directory like `/usr/kerberos`.

Does it mean kerberos is not installed on my server, and if not do I need to install it to get this to work, and how?!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a post from a user who solved this by [running configure under `sh -x`](http://www.sauers.com/blog/technology-and-car-doors/), which lets you see how it is figuring out which directories to look in. In this example, it was a lib vs lib64 directory issue that stopped PHP finding kerberos, but even if it's something else, it may help you discover what you need to set `--with-kerberos` to.

Comment: Thanks. From what I see it's looking for kbr5-config in /usr/bin, which happens to be there. The thing is, I don't know where kerberos is supposed to be on my system. I can't find any directory called kerberos or krb under /usr or /usr/local or /usr/lib and /usr/lib64 is a symlink to /usr/lib. Not sure if kerberos is something I should be installing separately?

Comment: libkrb5-dev should be all you need. You can check you have all the build dependencies with `apt-get build-dep php5-common`.

Comment: Ok. I tried that but I still get the same error. I'm wondering if it's an issue specific to Ubuntu Natty. I'm going to try it on Lucid and see what happens.